# Youtube embed in react controls, play onclick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, youtube

I have an iframe with a youtube video and a button, I want to play youtube video on button click

this is my code

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tu-bgIg-Luo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<button>Play</button>
```

Thanks

P.S. I am using react so the solution I need in react or in HTML/CSS/JS (Not a jQuery please)

Comment: Youtube API 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: I couldn't find any useful information there eligible for react, maybe I am searching bad but I searched for about an hour :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass url param in `autoplay` in youtube url:

like this

```
?autoplay=1
```

Here is complete code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [play, setPlay] = React.useState(false);
  const url = play
    ? `https://www.youtube.com/embed/tu-bgIg-Luo?autoplay=1`
    : `https://www.youtube.com/embed/tu-bgIg-Luo`;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <iframe
        width="560"
        height="315"
        src={url}
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
        allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>
      <button onClick={() => setPlay(true)}>Play</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-yonath-9z2hs?file=/src/App.js:0-556

Comment: Yeah that's what I also tried but it doesn't work :/ your codesandbox also doesn't work, maybe that's a new Youtube update?
EDIT: yeah autoplay doesn't work since April of 2018

Comment: I have updated code. Seems like working fine for me can you check again

Comment: It has some issue when you play with codesandbox. Try opening in different window: https://9z2hs.csb.app/

Comment: Oh yeah that worked !!!! what did you change to make it work???

Comment: Cool. I did two things: make url top level so every state change new url generated. And I opened in separate window not on with codesandbox editor. Codesandbox editor sometimes give error.So new url link I gave you is in different tab. Its working perfectly there